# How does the 'mv' command work?

Tags: linux

I used the command `mv` to move files from directory /a/b to directory /v/c. I wanted the whole 'b' directory to be moved to the path /v/c.

Now while running this command- `mv /a/b /v/c` I interrupted it in middle where the source had a large amount of data. Later I deleted directory 'c' since I thought it had partial files.

Now my question is will the directory 'b' contain all the original files along with the files that where moved to path /v/c? Or did I lose files by deleting the directory 'c'?

Comment: I recommend asking at http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I agree. You lost files. `mv` works file-by-file, so some files were already moved when you interrupted the command

Comment: `mv` does not move files but changes the inode.  Depending on where you interrupted it you may be hosed.

Comment: But when I saw the size of the source directory...it was same as before I used the 'mv' command

Comment: @jnbbender, `mv` only changes the inode via the rename() library call when it's within the same file system.  If the source and target are on different file systems, it's effectively a recursive `cp`.

Answer (score 2):

`mv` across filesystems will:

- create the destination directory
- for each file: copy and remove original
- remove origin directory

Thus, if you interrupt it, some of the files will have been moved but not all.  A `mv` of a directory within the *same* filesystem is atomic as it's just re-linking the directory's inode to a new location.

At one time, `mv` could only do the latter.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it depends on if the source and destination directories were on the same file system or different file systems.  If they were on the same file system then a "move" just changes the path information for each file.  But if they're on different file systems the "move" command will copy one file at a time, and subsequently delete it on the source.

So, in your scenario if the source and destination were on separate file systems then yes, you just lost files if you interrupted mv and then deleted "c".

Comment: `mv` on the same filesystem moves the directory, not the individual files.

Comment: But when I saw the size of the source directory...it was same as before I used the 'mv' command